# Prove that if $A$ is a positive definite matrix, then $A$ is non-singular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, positive-definite

First, going through what it means to be positive definite and non-singular:

Positive definite implies

- $\det(A) > 0$
- All eigenvalues of $A$ are positive, and so $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$

Nonsingular implies

- $\det(A) \neq 0$
- All eigenvalues of A are nonzero
- The product of eigenvalues of $A$ $= \det(A)$

It seems as though these two characterizations go hand in hand, though I assume negative eigenvalues could form a non-singular matrix but not a positive definite matrix. Can this be proven directly, or do I need to figure out how to prove by contradiction?

Thanks!

Comment: The proof of your statement in your title is obvious via definition. If you want a non-singular matrix that is not positive definite, we have $\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 &-1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I agree it is obvious given the assumption. However, I do need to write up a proof.

Comment: Do you actually want to prove it, or just based on logical arguments? Since $\det(A)>0$ implies directly that  $\det(A)\neq 0$ and there is your proof

Comment: If $A$ is singular, then $Av=0$ for some $v$, so $v^T A v =0$, contradicting positive definitness (if you use this definition)

Comment: It is a good rule to include the problem statement in the body of your Question.  In this case only the title provides the problem goal and setup.  This can be easily remedied.  Let me know if you prefer to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$\det(A) > 0 \Longrightarrow \det(A) \neq 0$$

Comment: Is it as straight-forward as: Given A is positive definite, the det(A)>0, which implies the det(A)=/=0. Thus A is non-singular. (?)

Comment: @5erena If you know, as you wrote it, that $A$ positive definite implies $\det(A) > 0$, yes, it is straightforward !

Answer (score 7):

Here's a one-line proof by contraposition:

Suppose there is nonzero $x$ such that $Ax = 0$. Then $\langle x, Ax \rangle = 0$, and so $A$ is not positive definite.

Answer (score 3):

We have that $\forall x \neq 0$

$$x^TAx>0 \implies  Ax\neq 0 \iff \text{A is full rank}$$

Answer (score 2):

If a square matrix with real entries is positive-definite, then its determinant is positive.

But not conversely: Some square matrices with real entries have a positive determinant without having only positive eigenvalues.