# Can we say whether a matrix is positive definite from the matrix propeties

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, singularity

By definition, a symmetric matrix $\mathrm{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is positive definite if for all $\mathrm{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{\mathrm{0}\}$, $\mathrm{x}^{\mathrm{T}} \mathrm{A} \mathrm{x}>\mathrm{0}$. I also understand that a positive definite matrix is nonsingular.

Can we draw the conclusion that if a general square matrix is singular, then it is not positive definite?

**EDIT**

I think that my question is conversely different from the one posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3826080/prove-that-if-a-is-a-positive-definite-matrix-then-a-is-non-singular), in the sense that I need to know if we can say the opposite; i.e., if $\mathrm{A}$ is singular, then $(\Rightarrow)$, is $\mathrm{A}$ not positive definite?

Thanks.

Comment: A singular matrix has at least one non-positive eigenvalue, doesn't it? ;-)

Comment: Nonono, you asked [singular => not positive definite]?, and this is equivalent to the contrapositive, answered in the proposed duplicate. Note that your "opposite" (i.e. the converse) is obviously false (you will easily find counterexamples), so I think you should remove your recent edit.

Comment: @AnneBauval: Yes, sorry. I need to know if $\mathrm{A}$ is singular, then $(\Rightarrow)$, is $\mathrm{A}$ not positive definite?

Comment: Indeed, and again: that is answered in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome, but now that you agree, please correct or remove your "EDIT". Your question is *not* different from the proposed duplicate. It is the same. Your last insertion of "I also understand that a positive definite matrix is nonsingular" also answers your question.